# Set time zone offset in Ruby

Tags: ruby, time

The default time zone offset in Ruby is apparently -0800. I want to set mine to -0500. How do I do this?

Comment: Change the time zone on your OS.

Comment: That worked. If you put that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: You should change the Ruby TZ variable. It is set by the host's operating system. Use TZ=EST to set your time zone to -05:00

Comment: It's worth noting that due to the disaster that is "Daylight Saving", choosing to specify "EST" and any similar "*ST" and "*DT" values is a very bad idea. EST does always mean -05:00, however it is the incorrect time zone for that region about 7 months out of the year. When setting this value, ALWAYS use the geographical name: "America/New_York" or "America/Los_Angeles" work great. For the exhaustive canonical list, see: https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo-data/tree/master/lib/tzinfo/data/definitions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the time zone on your OS; Ruby will pick up the change.

Comment: This solution works, but it isn't terribly portable.  It could cause your code to behave differently on different machines if they don't share this OS level setting.  You may be better off overriding the time-zone programmatically, but it really depends on your needs.  There are definitely scenarios where it's good to set your machine's time-zone to UTC, for example on servers.  However, it means your development machines would could be using a different time-zone, or other programs (such as an email/calendar client) would be forced to use UTC.

Comment: That worked great, but I was two hours late for my dentist appointment.

Answer (score 42):

Set the TZ environment variable...

```
$ ruby -e 'puts Time.now'
Sat Jan 15 20:49:10 -0800 2011
$ TZ=UTC ruby -e 'puts Time.now'
Sun Jan 16 04:49:20 +0000 2011
```

Ruby gets the time zone information from the host's operating system.

Most directly, it uses a C library API specified by C99 and Posix.

The implementation of that API is system-specific, on my Mac that means it consults `/etc/localtime` unless there is a TZ environment variable.

It's about the same on Linux.

Comment: Here is the list of available Time Zones
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html

Answer (score 36):

#### updated answer: use ActiveSupport

The more recent releases of Rails's ActiveSupport module offer a MUCH better solution in the active_support/time module.  (Note that modules in ActiveSupport can be loaded without dragging in all of Rails...)

I recommend this approach since it doesn't require setting any global state (e.g. setting the time zone on your OS or modifying `ENV['TZ']`) that might have unexpected side effects elsewhere.  Here's how you use it:

```
>> require 'active_support/time'
=> true
>> Time.at(1000000000).in_time_zone('US/Eastern')
=> Sat, 08 Sep 2001 21:46:40 EDT -04:00
>> Time.at(1000000000).in_time_zone('US/Pacific')
=> Sat, 08 Sep 2001 18:46:40 PDT -07:00
```

PS: if you want to see all of the time zone names supported, you can refer to:

```
>> ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING
=> => {"International Date Line West"=>"Pacific/Midway", "Midway Island"=>"Pacific/Midway", ...}
```

#### (original answer -- now outdated)

A bit late to the party, but found that I needed to set the time zone to different values according to user data.

What I used to do was (but see update below):

```
def with_time_zone(tz_name)
  prev_tz = ENV['TZ']
  ENV['TZ'] = tz_name
  yield
ensure
  ENV['TZ'] = prev_tz
end
```

Which permits things like:

```
>> with_time_zone('US/Eastern') { puts Time.at(1000000000) }
2001-09-08 21:46:40 -0400
>> with_time_zone('US/Pacific') { puts Time.at(1000000000) }
2001-09-08 18:46:40 -0700
```

Answer (score 15):

To programmatically set the ruby time zone, also set environment variables from within ruby by accessing the ENV hash:

```
ENV['TZ'] = 'UTC'
Time.at 0
#=> 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
```

This helps to avoid the need to modify your OS just for an app, and gives you more portability of your app if you move it to a different machine.  If you're using Rails, [ActiveSupport::TimeZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html) also offers some functionality to help with overriding the TimeZone.