# Can I override the system timezone in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, timezone, environment-variables

I'm here on *Ubuntu 12.04*, and I can see:

```
$ cat /etc/timezone 
America/Phoenix
```

Accordingly `Time` will return a time with a non-UTC zone:

```
$ irb
> Time.now
=> 2013-03-27 13:44:49 -0700
> Time.at 0
=> 1969-12-31 17:00:00 -0700
```

I can override the system time zone using the `TZ` environment variable:

```
$ TZ=UTC irb
> Time.now
=> 2013-03-27 20:47:19 +0000
> Time.at 0
=> 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
```

Is there anyway I can make this change programmatically, within a Ruby process?

Comment: Your question is pretty vague. Don't overestimate the helpfulness some context would provide.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also set environment variables from within ruby by accessing the `ENV` hash:

```
ENV['TZ'] = 'UTC'
Time.at 0
#=> 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
```

also see this answer: [Set time zone offset in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703830/set-time-zone-offset-in-ruby), It provides a way to write something like

```
with_time_zone 'UTC' do
  # do stuff
end

# now TZ is reset to system standard
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Time#gmtime`. For example

```
Time.now
# => Wed Mar 27 16:55:11 -0400 2013 
Time.now.gmtime
# => Wed Mar 27 20:55:14 UTC 2013 
Time.at(0)
# => Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 -0500 1969 
Time.at(0).gmtime
# => Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 UTC 1970
```

`Time#utc` also works and is an alias for `Time#gmtime`

Comment: That's great for figuring out how to get UTC-based times, but it doesn't help when the needed timezone isn't UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the use case, ActiveSupport offers a lot of TimeZone related goodness.

```
$ gem install activesupport
$ irb
> require 'active_support/time'            # => true
> Time.zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)' # => "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
> Time.zone.now                            # => Wed, 27 Mar 2013 16:14:19 PDT -07:00
```

ActiveSupport may be a larger dependency than you want, but you shouldn't overlook it.