# How do set ruby Gem Chronic's default timezone to Specific Timezone without rails

Tags: ruby, sinatra, chronic

## Question

By default, the Chronic gem uses the system timezone as the default timezone.

They mention here (https://github.com/mojombo/chronic#time-zones), that I can use ActiveSupports Time.zone to change this. But i'm not using Rails, i'm using Sinatra and including active support just to utilize the timezone class seems unnecessary.

How else can I do this?

## What i'm trying to do.

I'm using Chronic for system reporting / dashboards and stats.

The servers are storing timestamps in the created_at fields in the DB at utc time.
But of course we run our reports as PDT.

I want to set the default timezone to America/Los_Angeles.
So that:

```
d = Chronic.parse("1 days ago at midnight")  
date = d.localtime   #Should give me a date like "2013-05-27 00:00:00"
utc_date = date.utc  #Should give me a date like "2013-05-27 07:00:00"
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

I'd post this as a comment as I'm uncomfortable taking any credit for what is basically [someone else's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14659227/335847) but I wouldn't have enough room in the comments. The `TZ` environment variable is helpful in these situations. Take a look at this:

```
def with_time_zone(tz_name)
  prev_tz = ENV['TZ']
  ENV['TZ'] = tz_name
  yield
ensure
  ENV['TZ'] = prev_tz
end

with_time_zone('US/Pacific') { Chronic.parse("1 days ago at midnight") }
# => 2013-05-27 08:00:00 0100
with_time_zone('US/Pacific') { Chronic.parse("1 days ago at midnight").localtime }
# => 2013-05-27 00:00:00 -0700
```

You can either set the server's localtime with the correct zone, get the whole app to run with the `TZ` var set how you like, or manipulate the time on the way out.