# Why can't I modify a frozen Time in Twitter gem?

Tags: ruby, time, rubygems, twitter-gem

I have a Tweet object from the [twitter gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter), called `@tweet`.

I am able to do:

```
@tweet.created_at --> `@tweet.created_at.class` outputs `Time`
```

However, I want to change the timezone of `created_at`, so I tried:

```
@tweet.created_at.utc
```

And got:

```
can't modify frozen Time
```

How would I change from UTC−08:00 that my current `created_at` is, to CET time?

Comment: maybe `@tweet.created_at = Time.now.localtime("+01:00")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the `created_at` time field of the tweet has been frozen, you can't modify it, so `utc` will raise the `Exception`, because it tries to change value of `self`. Instead of modification you shell to duplicate the variable and reassign it:

```
@tweet.created_at = @tweet.created_at.dup.utc
```

Comment: Oh nice. I have a question though, how could I change the timezone from PDT (that I get) to CET?

Comment: what are the PDT and CET? pls see the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703830/set-time-zone-offset-in-ruby