# Configure date and timezone in Ruby

Tags: ruby, configuration, timezone, ini

I using some side api on my server what written in Ruby, and I found problem that  timezone in Ruby app is different from my (on server sets proper timezone), I try to find solution how to configure it (like in `php.ini`) but I only getting results to set it in code. Can somebody tell me can I configure it like in PHP, e.g. in some `ruby.ini` file? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby gets the time zone information from the host's operating system. So you can either:

- Change the time zone on your OS, or
- Set the TZ environment variable. Eg.

  `ENV['TZ'] = 'US/Eastern'`

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703830/set-time-zone-offset-in-ruby)