# How to set time zone with pure Ruby

Tags: ruby

In Rails it's easy to set default time zone. I just need to add `config.time_zone = 'Tokyo'` in config file.

How can I configure same way in pure ruby?

I mean "outside of Rails", of course it's OK to use some Gems like `ActiveSupport` or something else.

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703830.

Comment: Notice that using `ENV["TZ"]`, `"Tokyo"` will not work, as it is not a correct time zone. You have to do `ENV["TZ"] = "Asia/Tokyo"`.