# 'Time.at(seconds)' gives different time than 'fractions(seconds/60, seconds%60)'

Tags: ruby

I am executing this code:

```
t = DateTime.strptime('1:00:23', '%H:%M:%S')
t1 = DateTime.strptime('2:02:40', '%H:%M:%S')
t2 = t1.to_time - t.to_time
time_new = "#{(t2/3600).to_i}" + ":" +"#{((t2/60)%60).to_i}" + ":" + "#{(t2%60).to_i}"
time_units = time_new.split(':')
```

I get:

```
Time.at(t2).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
# => 06:32:17
"#{time_units[0]} hours, #{time_units[1]} minutes and #{time_units[2]} seconds"
# => 1 hours, 2 minutes and 17 seconds
```

which are very different. Why does `Time.at(seconds)` add 5 hours and 30 minutes?

Comment: try `Time.zone.at(t2).strftime("%H:%M:%S")`

Comment: It's because your time zone

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon tried "Time.zone.at(t2).strftime("%H:%M:%S")". It is giving me undefined method `zone' for Time:Class (NoMethodError)

Comment: right, you need set your timezone inside `application.rb` e.g. `config.time_zone = 'Mumbai'`

Comment: i am not using ruby on rails, it is just a simple ruby code

Comment: oops..sorry, my bad..

Comment: refer this answer.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14659227/6548745

Comment: What is the physical meaning of the object you are instantiating `Time.at(time_difference)` in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

> Why does `Time.at(seconds)` add 5 hours and 30 minutes?

Because you are comparing apples and oranges.

[`DateTime.strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) returns a `DateTime` instance in **UTC**. If you don't provide a date, it uses **today's date**:

```
DateTime.strptime('01:00:23')
#=> Tue, 06 Jun 2017 01:00:23 +0000
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^          ^^^^^
#         today                UTC
```

[`Time.at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Time.html#method-c-at) returns a `Time` instance in your **local time zone**, based on the number of seconds **since the epoch** (1 January 1970):

```
Time.at(1 * 3600 + 23)
#=> 1970-01-01 02:00:23 +0100
#   ^^^^^^^^^^          ^^^^^
#   not today          not UTC
```